# npm 'p-queue' and Generator function instead of async/await

Tags: javascript, react-native, generator, yield

Is it possible to use Generators instead of async/await function inside of
**queue.add(...)**?

Instead of this (it works):

```
queue.add(async () => {
   await Api.getSomeInfo() 
})
```

I need to use something like this (it doesn't work):

```
queue.add(function* () {
   yield Api.getSomeInfo() 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you could write helper function to convert generator to async function, something like this

```
const toAsync = (generator) => async () => {
  let g = generator()
  let result = g.next();
  while (!result.done) {
    const val = await result.value
    console.log(val)
    result = await g.next();
  }
}

const delay = (arg) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(arg),1000))

queue.add(toAsync(function* myGenerator() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    yield delay(i)
  }
}))
```